# Run python script saved on gdrive

Tags: python, gdrive

Hi is there a way to run a python script located/saved in certein gdrive folder?
I need this cause i want use python running on container but be able to modify py script whenever i need.
Is it possibile? Or is there a batter way?

Regard

Comment: You can download the script, then run it, sure.

Comment: Hi, any suggestion? You mean, when container start, download script and then run it?

Comment: Assuming you mean Google's cloud-based "GDrive", it depends on whether the container has the necessary credentials & libraries to access that API.  See the API docs here on how to interact programmatically: https://developers.google.com/drive

Comment: If you plan on modifying the script, then yes, the only option is to have the container download the script. You cannot build the container with it since that would be a static file. Your other option is to host the script as a lambda function instead of using containers

Answer (score 0):

solved downloading from github when container start.